# To feel undermined, stepped on

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word describing someone that felt undermined, stepped on by an action I did. It would work in a sentence like "I am sorry if I (word) you". I'm looking for a softer word than "offended", something with a more emotional connotation.

Comment: I think this is too localised. If you really don't think *"I am sorry if I offended you"* is sufficiently conciliatory, you need to find your own words and speak from the heart, not regurgitate a dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you, thanks for your concern but the only reason I posted this question is to find a word I've heard before.

Comment: np. Sorry if [I seemed dismissive of you](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+seemed+dismissive+of+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). There's certainly nothing wrong with asking, but I just don't think ELU should be voting on the "politeness" of various possible phrasings - imho that's etiquette, not language as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider *[slighted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slighted)*, the past participle of *[slight](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slight#Verb)*, which has senses including "To treat with disdain or neglect" and
"To act negligently or carelessly."  Much less formally, *to [diss](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diss)* means "To put (someone) down, or show disrespect by the use of insulting language or dismissive behaviour."

I think of *slight* and *diss* as slightly more neutral words than *offend*, rather than "more emotional".  Perhaps what you want are words that are "more sensitive" rather than  "more emotional".  For example, to say either "I'm sorry if I cut you off at the knees" or "I'm sorry if I knocked the stuffing out of you" would be more emotional but less sensitive.

Comment: +1 for "slighted", but I'd say that "dissed" sounds too much like slang to suit an apology ("I am sorry if I _dissed_ you").

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to apologize for what you did, and not for how you made them feel:

> I'm sorry that I overstepped my bounds.

In other words are you sorry for what you did, or do you feel justified in what you did and are just sorry that they felt slighted in the process?

Comment: This might be a pet peeve, but I don't like conditional apologies; they never seem sincere to me. Either you're sorry or you're not, but don't be sorry _only if_ something is the case. "I'm sorry _that_ I overstepped my bounds" might be better.

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks Jim - and now I need to apologise to you, because I just noticed that the OP had "sorry if" in the wording request... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use *upset* or *disrespected* there.

Answer (score 0):

Both *abrogated* and *derogated* would work, but I think jwpat7's answer fits better.